# Lookup Database (Multiple criteria)

Tags: excel, match, formula, lookup

Im having difficulty with the following, maybe you can help.

I need a formula to lookup the following details. I need it to do the following:

- Search Column 2 for "A"
- Filter the available rows by the criteria of column 3 having a value of "B1"
- Filter the available rows by the most recent date from column A
- Return the value from column D

```
DATE    A   A1  VALUE 1
DATE    C   D1  VALUE 1
DATE    B   F1  VALUE 1
DATE    A   A1  VALUE 1
DATE    C   P1  VALUE 1
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bKoT.jpg]

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Would you consider upvoting/accepting any of what was posted, if it was useful? This helps future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula:

```
=INDEX(D1:D6,MATCH(9^99,IF(IF((B1:B6="A")*(C1:C6="B1"),A1:A6)=MAX(IF((B1:B6="A")*(C1:C6="B1"),A1:A6)),ROW(D1:D6))))
```

This is an array formula however, so you'll have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work as intended.

Comment: Thanks, it just returns N/A?

Comment: @user2803971 Maybe a google doc? [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dG81YXVqbEFyNXNpVWlHd0xlUHA4aEE&usp=sharing) You might want to remove your email address as this is a public site.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, it works in google docs but as soon as i download it and open it in excel the formula returns #N/A. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2803971 Try this download file instead: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/2803971.xlsx) Hmm, otherwise are your dates in column A really dates or text typed as date?

Comment: @pnuts Oops, right. I took 'recent' for being smallest... derp moment there. Thanks!

Comment: Thats almost working perfectly! Thanks very much. The only issue is, i need the value returned from the row with the most recent date. At the moment its returning the value from the row with the oldest date?

Comment: Oh, just saw your comment there. Ill make the change and see if it works

Comment: @user2803971 Yes, that's what pnuts have pointed out. Find `MIN` in the function and change it to `MAX`.

Comment: Yep, thats fixed it. I cant thank you enough! Really big help, thanks very much